# How to decouple Python function as separate process?

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess, python-daemon

For example, I've got a function foo, and the caller function. I need foo to go to background, set lock file, set everything up, remove lock file. The caller must call foo and exit. I was thinking about `Subprocess` module, but as I see it can't do what I need from it to do. `python-daemon` seems to be promising, but I don't need it to run forever as a daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Might want to look at threading

```
import threading

def foo(my_args):
    # do something here

def caller(some_args):
    # do some stuff
    foo_thread = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=some_args)
    foo_thread.start()
    # continue doing stuff

caller()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can daemonize your function in a thread: e.g.

```py
import threading
import time

def worker(snooze):
    print(f'snoozing {snooze} seconds')
    time.sleep(snooze)


if __name__ == '__main___':

    task = threading.Thread(name='daemonize_worker', target=worker, args=(5, ))
    task.setDaemon(True)
    task.start()
```

This throws worker with snoozing of 5 sec in the background in a daemonized way.